# Android creating a launcher but not able to launch other apps

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-launcher

I am creating a launcher in android. Let me explain you the situation.

Case 1: When I run myLauncher app from android studio, it first runs as a normal app. And then I open the app drawer in myLauncher and click on an icon to start another app, it works fine. Upon exiting the app, I am again taken back to myLauncher as it was on the android stack. This is the behaviour I want.

Case 2: After my app installs on android, I press home button to choose the default launcher and then choose myLauncher as the default one. It opens and then I open the app drawer in myLauncher. Upon clicking any icon to start another app, it does not work.

Though I am working in cordova, but I don't think the issue is with cordova since everything works when myLauncher is not running as a launcher.

```
Intent launchIntent = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(args.get(0).toString());
cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Logcat for Case 1:

```
01-10 11:37:57.526  1555  1638 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.dialer cmp=com.android.dialer/.DialtactsActivity} from uid 10057 on display 0
01-10 11:37:57.526  1555  1638 W ActivityManager: Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result.
01-10 11:37:57.536  1555  1638 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f1132abef40, tid 1638
01-10 11:37:57.545  1236  1236 E EGL_emulation: tid 1236: eglCreateSyncKHR(1370): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
01-10 11:37:57.610  3983  3983 D CordovaInterfaceImpl: Sending activity result to plugin
01-10 11:37:57.612  1555  1638 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
01-10 11:37:57.629  3983  4017 W PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Apps.start blocked the main thread for 104ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
01-10 11:37:58.025  1555  1575 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.dialer/.DialtactsActivity: +333ms
01-10 11:37:58.308  3983  3983 I Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-10 11:37:58.464  3983  4025 E Surface : getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f11433b9d90
```

Logcat for Case 2:

```
01-10 11:34:15.739  1555  1803 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.android.dialer cmp=com.android.dialer/.DialtactsActivity} from uid 10057 on display 0
01-10 11:34:15.739  1555  1803 W ActivityManager: Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result.
01-10 11:34:15.791  1555  1575 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f1132cba040, tid 1575
01-10 11:34:16.463  1555  1575 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
01-10 11:34:16.566  1555  1638 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@668d511 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@20e786d
```

Comment: when you click on the icons, no action taking place, or just it opens and suddenly closes ?

Comment: No action takes place.

Comment: print the package for once that you are starting and let usknow

Comment: The package name is in logcat `pkg=com.android.dialer cmp=com.android.dialer/.DialtactsActivity`

Comment: @HasifSeyd it opens and suddenly closes. I noticed this behavior when I tapped the app icon multiple times very fast.

Comment: @AdityaGoel can you take the complete logs and just check if fatal crash or exception is thrown

Comment: No, there is no fatal crash or exception.

Comment: The strange part is the code works flawlessly if the app is not running as a launcher. Perhaps some permission issues?

Answer (score 0):

I made two changes and <strike>it works now</strike>

In manifest I added `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the activity and the intent launch I put inside a runnable.

```
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent launchIntent = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(args.get(0).toString());
                    launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launchIntent);
                } catch (JSONException exp) {
                    Log.e("ERR", "JSON Error");
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    Log.e("ERR", "Other Error: " + exp.getMessage());
                }

            }
```

Update:
No this is not working. Must have mixed up apks. If I keep tapping the app icon very fast, then that app does open and closes instantaneously.